# How to call a Widows Form Object over it's name (string)?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, object, methods

Normally we create a form like;

```
MainForm form1 = new MainForm();
form1.show();
```

But I want to call this form1 over it's name something like;

```
string FormName = "MainForm";

// a method should be here that gives us form1 from FormName
// then;

form1.show();
```

how can I do that? 
infact, my goal is to show a form by string name which is comming from sql database. Because I have too many windows forms in my project, so I prefer to call forms over sql database

Comment: So something like `form1 = GetForm(FormName)`? (obviously not real code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

If the name is the same as the type name as in your example, you can use reflection:

```
private static string namespacePrefix = "MyNamespace.";

public static Form CreateFormByName(string formName)
{
    Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Type formType = myAssembly.GetType(namespacePrefix + formName);
    if (formType == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Form type not found");
    return (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
}
```

**Option 2:**

When type names and form names are different, you should use a dictionary mapping:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Type> mapping = new Dictionary<string, Type>
{
    { "MainForm", typeof(Form1) },
    { "frmOptions", typeof(OptionsForm) },
    // ...
}

public static Form CreateFormByName(string formName)
{
    Type formType;
    if (!mapping.TryGetValue(formName, out formType))
        throw new ArgumentException("Form type not found");
    return (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
}
```

Comment: then I tried this  System.Windows.Forms.Form form1 =  CreateFormByName("MyFormName");
            form1.Show(); // and it works!!! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through the `Type.GetType` and `Activator.CreateInstance` methods. The `Activator` method will give you a return of type `object` that represents your newly created object.

```
string FormName = "MainForm";
Type t = Type.GetType(FormName);
Form f = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Form;
f.show();
```

Comment: Or `Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName)`

Comment: so how to convert it to Forms.Form and calling show() method? I've tried this,     Type t = Type.GetType(FormName);
            Form form1 = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            form1.Show(); // but it didn't work